# ModelAndView and byte[] within Spring MVC controller

Tags: java, hibernate, servlets, spring-mvc

I have a following mapping which retrieves some "scene" details and shows it inside jsp page.

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/{id}",method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public ModelAndView showScene(@PathVariable String id){
         ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("/Scene/scene");
                 //retrieving Scene using Hibernate                 
                 Scene scene = service.getScene(Long.parseLong(id));
         mv.addObject("name", scene.getName());
                 mv.addObject("desc", scene.getDescription());
                 //etc....
         return mv;
     }
```

My problem is that one of the fields in scene object is png image as byte[] and I need to show it. I understand that I can create another controller which will handle all the .png extentions request and return byte[]. Something like:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>PNGHandler</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

and send reference to an image as:

```
mv.add("image", "image/"+scene.getId()+".png");
```

but then I'll need to retrieve byte[] again in png controller and it will cost me additional Hibernate Transaction. Is there any work around I can do to save this transaction and not to retrieve byte[] twice?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say - separate the bytes to a different Hibernate mapped entity (maybe Image?), and make Scene refer it via a lazy-loaded relationship.

Then you will have the power to load Images only when you really need them. As already mentioned, the Controller executing showScene doesn't need to load the images, they can be handled by a different Controller.

The advantages of this will be:

- You can improve your apps performance by setting images to be cached for a specific amount of time in browsers. This means your Controllers that load images won't be hit all the time, thus reducing load on the serverside. However, if you store images in the session, they will be loaded all the time, irrespective of cache settings set for them.
- Not all requests to showScenes will end up with success or will require images to be shown. Forcing images to load all the time seems to much effort.
- This might be a personal preference, but I like sessions to be kept as clean and as light as possible.
- Server-side caching is a good idea, but don't do that in the session. How about Hibernate's second layer caching - something to be shared by all users?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is for the first request to store the `byte[]` (or the whole `Scene` object) in the session, and for the second request to fetch it from the session and stream it back to the client. You could wither store the data in the session under a fixed key, or you could generate a new key each time, store it in the session under that key, and then encode the key into the `<img>` URL when you render the page.

You'd have to be careful not to put too many images in the session, so you could delete them after they've been retrieved, or only allow one in the session at one time.

Comment: Yes, thank you.Sure I can use Session, but I was thinking about kind of "Spring MVC" way to do that :)

Comment: @danny: You can use `@SessionAttributes` to do that, but in my opinion, it's not worth it - just use the raw Session object.

Comment: Using a session could possibly prevent you application from scaling well (for example if you have two web server and need to make the session aviable at both of them). And like skaffman already mentioned you need to take care about the number of sessions: If you have so many (and big) sessions that they will be persisted, then this soulution would your make performance even more worse then if you would access the data base twice. Because when the session would be persisted, then you have to write the array and read it again. This would be much slower than read it from the database.

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate provides lazyloading for attributes http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-lazyproperties

I belive the spring way would be to use two controller methods, one containing the page like you did, and a second one returning only the image.

If you are scared about the performance, you could use the hibernate property lazyloading for your byte array. So the array will be not loaded when you only use the name and other stuff (except the array).

But as far I know, the property lazy loading needs some kind of byte code anhancement. So if this is a huge problem, you could think of loading the attributes directly with an query instead of loading it by the mapped class.